# symfony twig background image

Tags: css, symfony, twig

I need to know why this script doesn't work with me and If anyone has a solution it will be appreciated.
My problem is that the image wouldn't be displayed `background-image:url('{{asset('uploads/images/')}}{{image.name}}`

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        {% set i = 0 %}
        {% for project in projects %}
            {% for image in project.images[:1] %}
                {% if i == 0 %}
                    <div class="item active">
                    {% else %}
                        <div class="item">
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('{{asset('uploads/images/')}}{{image.name}}')"></div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% set i = i + 1 %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What HTML gets rendered and what do you expect?

Comment: I edited the post right now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your `image.name` inside of the `asset()` function.

`{{asset('uploads/images/')}}{{image.name}}` changed to

`{{asset('uploads/images/' ~ image.name)}}`

Comment: Twig's string concatenation operator is `~`, not `.`